# Stop html5 audio player from auto-playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I've been using this script to play a list of songs: http://jsfiddle.net/WsXX3/33/

Sadly my javascript is lacking and I hope someone there can help!

How do I stop this script from automatically playing? I want the sound to be user-initiated. I've tried using preload="none" in the html code but that has no impact, so I'm guessing its in the javascript.

```
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .10;
    audio[0].play();
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
```

Comment: start commenting off lines in `init`, you're going to find the line that make the music start playing.

Comment: remove audio[0].play();

Comment: Its a bug... well sort of.. Your audio tag was not terminated correctly..See my answer with a new fiddle linked

Comment: I removed the audio[0].play(); from the init function and it now works as expected. A bunch of answers in just a few mins, thanks so much guys, you  all rock!

Comment: You might want to double check this in a few other browsers, Chrome for windows here still did not work with just the audio[0].play() being removed.  I would suggest running your code through something like http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your corrected Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WsXX3/1014/

Removed/commented out the play inside of init.. 
But the bug is that you need to close your source tag correctly using XHTML standards... added the trailing slash in the end of the source tag

```
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>

// audio[0].play();
```

**XHTML Self Closing Tags**

Refer to this link for an example / information: http://www.devwebpro.com/self-closing-and-end-tags-in-xhtml-and-html/

Basically... if the element/tag has two parts like a div/form/span/p/h1 then you use it as

If the element only has a single part/tag.. like img/hr/source then you need to add the closing slash as the last item just before the >

So in this case, my google chrome picked up the issue with the missing slash and made all the difference

**EDIT** - Conflicting information... Test for your own situation.

After coming across this, i decided to read a little about html5 tags as i have yet to rely on using them (my main development needs to support cross browser and older browser such as >=IE8.

It seems that HTML actually does not treat ending tags the same as XHTML/XML. One of the other things here to note is what DOC TYPE your using as well. So its something people might want to test all combinations first and narrow down the most reliable combination of DOC TYPE & closing a single tag type element ..eg SOURCE

Comment: The removal of "audio[0].play();" did the trick!There is a </audio> tag on line 4, is the "/>" still required?

Comment: Yes its still required, as its a separate tag/element..  Each tag/element needs to be closed correctly according to XHTML standards or certain browsers and versions may fail.

Comment: As long as you got it working, thats all that counts. But i would suggest making sure its valid markup... You will notice when you add the slash, the red </audio> tag in your fiddle becomes the normal green color.. This is a hint that its not valid.

Comment: Thanks Mayhem, I followed your example and its looking good across the browsers I need it to!